# Proving relative homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic relative to $A$

$h,k:Y \rightarrow Z$ are homotopic relative to $B$ and $f(A) \subset B$

I need to show that $hf$ is homotopic to $kg$ relative to $A$.

I have proven that hf and hg are homotopic relative to $A$ by taking composition of homotopy connecting $f$ and $g$ and h.

I am not able to show anything further.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: try proving that hf ~ kf and kf ~ kg relative to A.

Comment: Done thanks a ton